# How to count the gate voltage and drain current from the forward transconductance value?

Tags: mosfet

How do i get the ratio of `Vgate/Idrain` according to the value of the forward transconductance in the MOSFET data sheet? The units i got is 6 siemens, but i don't know how many is 6 siemens? Note that i'm a beginner.

Comment: 6 siemens is 6 amps per volt. 3 volts gate to source means 18 amps drain current for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 siemens is 6 amps per volt in drain current.